# Is there any Yarn equivalent of npx preact create?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, preact, preact-cli

I am trying to run the `preact create` command using Yarn. It's simple to run `preact create ..... .....` or `npx preact create ... ....`. It works fine and both of the commands use npm. But I am trying to run the command using Yarn. I have tried the following commands but nothing works. The error says "couldn't find a package.json file in path".

`yarn preact create .... ....`

`yarn dlx preact create .... ....`

`yarn preact-cli create .... ....`

`yarn dlx preact-cli create .... ....`

So, what should I do to run the command using Yarn. One alternative maybe is running the command using npm and then running yarn install and then running npm uninstall. But what's the actual way?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no Yarn equivalent for `npx`. The Yarn team thought `npx` was enough.

That being said, we support creating a new Preact CLI project with Yarn through the `--yarn` flag.

```
npx preact-cli create ... --yarn
```

https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli#cli-options

Please do note that when using Preact CLI via NPX, you do need to use `preact-cli`. `npx preact` gives you the Preact library.

Comment: Thank you @rschristian for this useful answer. But the above line of code doesn't work. It still uses npm to install the dependencies. But thank you for informing me about the --yarn flag. I used it while running `preact create ...... ...... --yarn` and it works fine. Though `preact create` isn't an alternative to npx.

Comment: You're saying `npx preact-cli create ... --yarn` doesn't install using yarn? Mind raising an issue in our tracker? I can't reproduce and I don't see how that could happen but it's clearly something we need to address.

Comment: Yeah, it's not working. Well, I'll open an issue in the github repo of preact.

Comment: Make sure it's Preact-CLI, not Preact. Different things. But I'll take a look there.

Comment: Hmm.. I tried running the command again before raising a issue in issue tracker. But now I see that it uses npm at first to install preact-cli (as I didn't install preact-cli using yarn). Then it uses to yarn to create the preact-app. So, it's normal I think and I am not raising an issue..

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's normal. NPX, if you didn't know, is a way or globally installing an app with NPM that is not accessible, i.e., you can't actually use it outside of NPX. The install will then be deleted overtime when the cache is cleared. NPX is used to setup Preact-CLI, as Yarn does not offer an equivalent, but we use the package manager of your choice for installing the dependencies into your new project.

Answer (score 14):

UPDATED: there is `yarn dlx` in v2

> Run a package in a temporary environment.

https://yarnpkg.com/cli/dlx

Feature was requested in yarn
https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3937

So package developers need to think for both npm and yarn users.

Comment: This should become the new accepted answer now that yarn 2 (aka yarn berry) has come out.

Comment: It should not, as it would not solve the user's problem. The `--yarn` flag is what determines the package manager for Preact-CLI (though that tool is now unmaintained).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ynpx` as an equivalent.

`yarn global add ynpx`

Then do your `npx` commands as normal, using `ynpx` in place of `npx`

eg.

```
ynpx preact create ...
```

Answer (score 3):

For a TL;DR [answer](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3937#issuecomment-315842189) from the thread mentioned above.
You can find the following.

> `npx` performs no operations which clash with people using other package managers [...] So you could say `npx` is `ypx`, unless you feel really strongly about cache-sharing, which is a pretty thing.
> For the probable reasoning of not creating a `ypx` specific command

Answer (score -1):

Yarn now supports create cli as following

`yarn create [your-cli-name] [..arugments]`

for eg. `yarn create expo-app hello-world`

Comment: This is not relevant for `preact-cli`. `yarn create` and `npm init` only work with packages prefixed with `create-`, i.e,, `create-foo` -> `yarn create foo`. Preact-CLI, at this time, does not offer a package in this format so your answer is wrong in context.

Comment: correct, my answer is more general and not relevant to `preact-cli`.

Comment: If it's not relevant for `preact-cli` then it's not relevant to this question. This question is about how to initialize a `preact-cli` project with yarn.

Answer (score -1):

One alternavite would be using vite with yarn.

```
yarn create vite your-project --template=preact
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. The user was asking how to create a new Preact-CLI project with Yarn; Vite is a separate tool entirely.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34308554)

Comment: @rohit-gupta, rschristian True, this answer doesn't address the preact-cli issue, Only gives alternative way to create preact app using yarn and vite

Comment: That's not how this site works. Do not provide answers that you know do not address the issue the OP is facing. It provides no value.